# perl string manipulation

Tags: string, perl

I have a file with lines like:

```
analogy of dinner, 12312-12351, http://wwwdinner.com
```

Sometimes the lines are like:

```
eggs,bread,bacon:breakfast, 12312-1565A, http://wwwdinner.com
```

I want to split the string up into 3 parts using commas or something, but sometimes the front part has commas, so I do not know how.

I only need the front part and the back part. I do not need the middle part, which is the numbers part; but sometimes there are letters there too.

Comment: You can use regular expression to match three parts: 1. a set of nonnumerical characters; 2. a set of numerical characters connected by a dash; 3. a standard URL.

Comment: Do you control the format of the file?  Assuming the number of comma-separated terms in the first part can vary, comma separation within the first part and comma delimiting the parts themselves is rough.  Ideally you would delimit the parts with a delimiter that does not appear within the parts themselves - e.g. `|`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use split here:

```
split /, /,$_; #split for every (<comma><space>)comma followed by a space
```

for eg:

```
> echo "eggs,bread,bacon:breakfast, 12312-1565A, http://wwwdinner.com"|perl -lne '@a=split /, /;print $a[0]'
eggs,bread,bacon:breakfast
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first use split.

```
my @p=split/,/ ;
```

Then join the first several parts together

```
$first=join(",",@p[0..scalar(@p)-3]);
$second=$p[-2];
$third=$p[-1];
```

Comment: you can also pop the last 2 elements so your join can be much cleaner. $third = pop @p; $second = pop @p; $first = join ...

Comment: @erickb: You missed the main point of your suggestion. Once the last two items are removed like that, rebuilding the first field becomes simply `join ',', @p`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a regex and anchor it to some part of your strings that are consistent.

For example, to convert to pipe "|" separated:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.*), ([0-9]*-[0-9]*), (.*)/$1|$2|$3/' < f
analogy of dinner|12312-12351|http://wwwdinner.com
eggs,bread,bacon:breakfast|12312-12351|http://wwwdinner.com
```

Where the [0-9]*-[0-9]* matches any series of numbers with a dash between them.  23-123213, 9-1234 and 123123213-4 would all match for example.  Putting the expressions in () "memorizes" them and they can be referred to later by number: $1 = the first memorized field, $2 = the second, etc.

http://codeidol.com/perl/effective-perl/Regular-Expressions/Use-regular-expression-memory./

The reason the first pattern "(.*)," matches to the last "," not the first is because perl regex's are by default "greedy" - they try to match as much as possible.

http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#Greedy

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell what is the best option without knowing the full range of possibilities of your data. But it seems best to focus on the middle, unwanted field that I think should be two sequences of digits or capital letters joined by a hyphen. Is that right?

Then you can parse the lines using a simple regex, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  if (my @parts = /^(.+),\s*([0-9A-Z]+-[0-9A-Z]+),\s*(.+)$/) {
    printf "%s ~ %s\n", @parts[0,2];
  }
}

__DATA__
analogy of dinner, 12312-12351, http://wwwdinner.com
eggs,bread,bacon:breakfast, 12312-1565A, http://wwwdinner.com
```

**output**

```
analogy of dinner ~ http://wwwdinner.com
eggs,bread,bacon:breakfast ~ http://wwwdinner.com
```

Comment: what does @parts = /^(.+),\s*([0-9A-Z]+-[0-9A-Z]+),\s*(.+)$/ mean? This method worked for 80% of the lines in my file so I am figuring out why. I have just started perl so I'm not really sure

Comment: Parentheses in a regex cause those parts of a successfully-matched string to be *captured* into variables `$1`, `$2` etc. If you assign the result of a pattern match to an array then those strings will be put into the array as well, so `$parts[0]` contains `$1` etc. If you look at the data lines for which this code didn't work, then the middle section will look like something other than `12312-1565A`. Perhaps there is no hyphen, or there is a character other than digits and capital letters. If you show me these lines then I can fix my code for you.

Answer (score 0):

For fun,

```
my @fields = reverse map "".reverse, split /\s*,/, reverse($_), 3;
```

Seriously,

```
my @fields = /^(.*),\s*(\S+),\s*(\S+)\z/;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `split /([^:]*:)?([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)/g, $str`.

Here are few examples:

```
my $str = "eggs,bread,bacon:breakfast, 12312-1565A, http://wwwdinner.com";
my @parts = split /([^:]*:)?([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)/g, $str;

print $parts[1]; #eggs,bread,bacon:
print $parts[2]; #breakfast
print $parts[3]; # 12312-1565A
print $parts[4]; # http://wwwdinner.com"
```

And respectively if you use the first string:

```
my $str1 = "analogy of dinner, 12312-12351, http://wwwdinner.com";
my @parts = split /([^:]*:)?([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)/g, $str1;

print $parts[2]; #analogy of dinner
print $parts[3]; # 12312-1565A
print $parts[4]; # http://wwwdinner.com"
```

Comment: I would still need the "eggs,bread,bacon" as it is included in the first like a title of a book